# javascript How Array.prototype.push concatenates

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I've seen the Array's push method used to replace concatenation, but I'm not entirely sure how it works.

```
var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [4,5,6];
Array.prototype.push.apply(a,b);
```

How does this concatenate in place rather than returning a new array?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) takes two arguments:

```
fun.apply(thisArg[, argsArray])
```

You're passing `a` as your `this` object and `b` as your argument list, so your code is really calling `.push()` with the elements of `b` as your arguments:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a.push(4, 5, 6);
```

Now, `.push()` just mutates your original array.

Comment: @NULL: Why do you say that?

Comment: It does. I had a little brain fart there thinking that push returned a new array. But, I saw this in code and I'm confused `Array.prototype.push.apply(a,b)`. Why would you do that instead of just `a.push(b)`. I thought it must be doing something different.

Comment: @NULL: That's an implementation detail. It's not something you can actually explain.

Comment: @Blender Is `Array.prototype.push.apply(a,b)` different than `a.push(b)`?

Comment: @Jeff: if `a` is not of type `Array`, they'll do different things (apart from the difference between `call` and `apply`)

Comment: @JeffStorey: Yes. `.apply()`'s second argument is a list of arguments. `a.push(b)` would be `Array.prototype.push.apply(a, [b])`.

Answer (score 4):

Using `this`. To try to describe it see this customPush function.

```
function customPush() {
    var i = 0,
        len = arguments.length;

    for(; i < len; i++) {
        this[this.length] = arguments[i];
    }
};


var a = [1,2,3];
var b = [4,5,6];
customPush.apply(a,b);
```